# same function for Mouse Click and Key Press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call a function in jquery when mouse click or key press is occure

one way is to write same code twice for this both event but it is not proper way

can any one tell me how it is possible?

Comment: You can create a function and have it registered for both events.

Comment: You can create a jquery function and have it registered for both jquery events

Answer (score 2):

write a function

```
function Process(){
//Put all your logic
}

call the function in all the event 

$("some element selector").on("click keypress",function() {
     Process();
});
```

or any other click event.

Answer (score 1):

Write only one function & call it on both event.

```
$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
```

funABC();
});

```
    $( "#target" ).click(function() {
```

funABC();
});

```
function funABC(){alert("DONE");}
```

One more shortcut :

```
    $( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).keypress();
});


   $( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
funABC();
});
```

Comment: how it is possible in jquery? (element).click(function() { });

Comment: $(document).on("keypress mouseenter","input",function(){});

Comment: @Kasma `mouseenter` is not a click event

Comment: yeah, he can use mousedown or click, it was just example o combining two event into one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to register both handlers to the same element then you can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register handler for multiple events

```
$('myelementselector').on('click keypress', function () {
    //mycode
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `on` method.

```
$("some element selector").on("click keypress",function() {
     //do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use like

```
<input type="text"  />


$(document).on("click mouseenter","input",function(){});
```

Comment: `mouseenter` isn't a click event

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

$(element).on('click keypress keydown', function() {

});

Answer (score 0):

You also use :

```
$( "input" ).on('keypress mouseup',function() {

 alert('done');

});
```

or

```
$( "input" ).on('keypress mouseup',fun);
```